# Where is the Riak CentOS installation directory?

Tags: centos, database, yum, centos-5, installation-package

Used "yum install riak" on CentOS 5.8, and easily found the config files in `/etc/riak`. However, I can't find where the data files and installation files are located. Anyone know where they are? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can usually figure out where RPM puts stuff by asking it:

`rpm -ql riak`

Will tell you where all the files from the 'riak' package were put.

Answer (score 0):

Found it after some digging: `/var/lib/riak`

This page from the docs was also helpful http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/cookbooks/Backups/